# Как установить аватар профиля через vk_api?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Как можно установить аватар через vk_api? Есть ли такой метод?

Answer (score 0):

Этот метод есть в документации

https://dev.vk.com/method/photos.saveOwnerPhoto